# Bootstrap iframe wont play my local video

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I created a backend server using golang for my videos and I want to embed them on my page but the video does not play, it's just all black. Then when I try to use a youtube video it works.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" :src="videoSource" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I use vue.js

```
videoSource: '192.168.254.31:9998/mediaSource/myVideo.mp4'
```

My server works because when I try I directly on chrome the videos plays automatically.

Comment: Can you check in the console and tell if you are getting any CORS error ? It could be the root cause of it.

Comment: "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute."